# Browser-only cache-control - Not CDN

Tags: php, cache-control

I'd like to apply this to browsers:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');
```

But apply this to my CDN:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

In other words I want the CDN to treat it as dynamic content but browsers to still store the response in their local cache. Is there any standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=3600
```

So that an eventual CDN/intermediate proxy is bypassed.